# What is this vent called?

Tags: basement, vent

Hi I need to get this vent/pipe replaced but I don’t know what it is called. Can anyone identify it for me. It’s in my basement near the furnace.

[image]

Comment: What is the other end connected to? Is it actually cemented into the wall as it appears, or is there room around it to _easily_ remove & replace it? Could you maybe provide a pic from the side? How big is it?

Answer (score 1):

Lacking context, it's either a cleanout (normally at the **bottom** of a flue) or a disused thimble (place where a pipe **used to** connect to the flue) with a cover/plug in it (the half-rusted bit with the handle) - "cleanout cover" and "end cap" and "flue plug" are all possible names when searching. Add the diameter of the pipe/hole to narrow results towards ones that might actually fit.